# There is no knowledge so certain that no one can doubt it

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-mind

Thoughts? Just something to think about!

Comment: I'm not so sure about that...

Comment: Yes, we can be certain about counter examples to a claim. For instance, if I claim there are no building structures over 6 feet tall then you see a garage or a house taller than 6 feet tall we can be CERTAIN the original claim I made is false. All apples are red fruits. Wait minute there are green apples. We have a counter example. If the counter example is accurate then the original claim must be false with certainty. No one reasonable can doubt a clear, concise & accurate counter example. Here is another claim: there are only four human beings on the entire planet. We know it is false.

Comment: Isn't there no doubt that is so uncertain that we can't know it, too? Or "no question that is so debatable that we can't know the answer to it"?

Comment: Yes, we are certain that there are no human knowledge that is certain...

Comment: I think Searle has an opposing view: “where consciousness is concerned the existence of the appearance is the reality.” *The Mysery of Consciousness*, which of course others like Dennett deny it so there are doubters. It’s not clear if you’re   seeking public consensus (then Searle’s doesn’t fit), or seeking arguments that there exists certain kinds of irrefutable knowledge, then Searle’s seems to fit.

Answer (score 1):

Doubt is a state of mind, and the claim you make is empirical. Regardless of the quality of evidence, it seems that there is some agent somewhere, that underneath the influence of an aging mind, drugs, coercion, etc will be able to doubt such a claim.

Perhaps the better question is this: is there knowledge that cannot be rationally denied?

Comment: No. And I'm really sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

> dubito, ergo sum

Descartes' certainty in doubt established for him his ego, but as (at least) Heidegger later pointed out, what was established was also the opening to a clearing, the opening of (something) truth—not just ego.

However the truth of what appears can also refuse to reveal itself, or conceal itself, vis. [The Origin of The Work of Art](http://users.clas.ufl.edu/burt/filmphilology/heideggerworkofart.pdf)

pages 28-29

> The critical concepts of truth which, since Descartes start out from
> truth as certainty, are mere variations on the definition of truth as
> correctness. This familiar essence of truth, truth as the correctness
> of representation, stands and falls with truth as the unconcealment of
> beings.
>
> When, here and elsewhere, we conceive of truth as unconcealment, we are not merely taking refuge in a more literal formulation of the Greek word. We are reflecting upon that which, unexperienced and unthought, underlies our familiar and therefore worn out essence of truth in the sense of correctness.

page 31

> In the immediate circle of beings we believe ourselves to be at home.
> The being is familiar, reliable, ordinary. Nonetheless, the clearing
> is pervaded by a constant concealment in the twofold form of refusal
> and obstructing. Fundamentally, the ordinary is not ordinary; it is
> extra-ordinary, uncanny [un-geheuer].

Truth is also the un-truth: we see the refused and the obstructed (camouflaged).  We wrestle with the strife of figuring it out. That's the truth that you can be certain of.